# docker container port map with remote IP (54.xxx.xxx.23) on local development

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm working as a DevOps for some of the Projects Where I am facing an issue,

I have one docker-compose.yml which is working fine with local IP like 192.168.0.38 but I want to map it with my AWS IP (54.xxx.xxx.23) instead of local host IP.

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    build: ./api
    image: api
    environment:
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
    expose:
      - ${scikiqapiport}
    ports:
      - ${scikiqapiport}:${scikiqapiport}
    command: 
       "python3 manage.py makemigrations"
    command: 
       "chmod -R 777 ./scikiq/scikiq/static:rw"
    command: 
       "python3 manage.py migrate" 
    command: "gunicorn --workers=3 --bind=0.0.0.0:${scikiqapiport} wsgi"
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - base
    volumes:
      - "../compressfile:/home/data/arun/compressfile"
      - "static:/home/data/arun/scikiq/scikiq/static:rw"


  scikiqweb:
    build: ./web
    image: web
    ports:
      - ${scikiqwebport}
    command:
      "gunicorn --workers=3 --bind=0.0.0.0:${scikiqwebport} wsgi"
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - base

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - ${scikiqwebport}:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:     
      - scikiqweb1

  base:
    build: ./base-image
    image: scikiq_base
volumes:
  compressfile:
  static:
```

Your help will be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Q: What exactly "isn't working"?  Where do you think the problem might lie?

Comment: my all three docker compose services is working fine with system host IP(192.168.1.111) but I want to use my aws IP (54.149.148.23) instead of system host IP Ip.

Comment: any can Help to resolve this issue??

Comment: Is you AWS Elastic IP mapped to your instance?

Comment: this ip (54.149.148.23 ) is mapped with my instance.

Answer (score 4):

Put the public IP where is used local IP its working